# Перенос строк в редакторе Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Добавляю в `strings.xml` в Андроид Студии большие тексты. В одну строчку их практически невозможно читать.

Когда-то настроил для одного из приложений авто перенос строк, которые не влазят в экран. Но сейчас не могу найти/вспомнить как.

Выглядело это примерно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, где что нажать, чтобы повторить этот эффект.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно настроить глобально через настройки.

```
Configure > Settings > Editor > галочка 'Use soft wraps in editor'
```

Либо

```
Preferences -> Editor -> General -> галочка 'Use soft wraps in editor'
```

Но проще всего как-то вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю с какой это версии и на какой системе, ибо скриншот из сети.

На MacOS в Android Studio 3.1.2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто нажмите на номер строки правой кнопкой мыши.

Comment: Точно! Отлично, спасибо :)

Comment: Спасибо, даже не знал о такой фиче)